# Enable TextField if RadioButton selected option is NO

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can you please help me with the code

Comment: You forgot to provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

This simple example will get you started.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form id="f">
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}">
            <apex:selectoption itemValue="1000" itemLabel="1000"></apex:selectoption>
            <apex:selectoption itemValue="2000" itemLabel="2000"></apex:selectoption>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="f"/>
        </apex:selectRadio>
        <apex:inputText value="{!Account.Name}" disabled="{!Account.AnnualRevenue != 2000}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You need to pass account id as parameter to this page as this page uses Account standard controller.

At first the account name text box will be disabled since Annual Revenue is not equal to 2000. When you select the 2000 radio button, it will enable the account name text box.

You should tweak this to fulfill your scenario. Hope it helps.

Comment: If the provided answer resolved your question, mark it so others get benefit from the answer.